# My Array.sorts is not printing as intended

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

My Arrays.sort is being ignored. The array is being printed without being sorted. I tried adding different parameters and placing it in different places but haven't had any luck. My program is suppose to sort the array during\after it reads ints from a file.

```
package filterSort;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;




public class FilterSort {

    public static int[] doubleArrayAndCopy(int[] arr) {
        
        int len = arr.length;
        
        
        int max = arr.length * 2;
        int[] copyArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr,max);
        int length = copyArr.length-1;
        Arrays.sort(copyArr, 0, length);
        
        return copyArr;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = new int[8];
       
        
       
        try {
            File file = new File("data.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
            
            
            for(int i = 0; myReader.hasNext(); i++) {
                
                if(i == data.length - 1) {
                    
                    data = doubleArrayAndCopy(data);
                    
                    
                }else {
                
                    if(myReader.hasNextInt()) {
                        data[i] = myReader.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(data[i]);
                    }else {
                        myReader.next();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        
    }

}
```

This is my output:

```
4
44
99
1
2
9
3
4
90
162
92
0
1
22
4
2
3
99
-8
100
99
-3
98
```

I need it to be sorted in that format.

If I place the System.out.println and Arrays.sort at the end:

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    Arrays.sort(data, 0, data.length - 1);
   
    for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(data[j]);
    }
```

It sorts it, but it outputs all the extra 0s from the empty indexes.

Comment: You're printing out the data as you're reading it, not the sorted array. Use `Arrays.toString(data)` to get a String representation out of your array (or use a `for` loop to print it out), and do it *after* you've done the reading and sorting. Your `System.out.println` is in the wrong place. You could leave the sort after the reading as well, there's no need to sort it every time you double the size, is there?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to print your sorted array after each 8 items,if I this is right, try to print the `copyArr` in the function ,then return an empty one .and add this code after the for loop

```
if(data[0]!=null){
  data = doubleArrayAndCopy(data);}
```

hope that will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws in the existing code:

1. In `doubleArrayAndCopy` the input array should be sorted and only after that its size should be doubled.
   Upon duplication `0`'s will be added to the end of array.
   Thus, method `doubleArrayAndCopy` can be rewritten as:

```java
public static int[] doubleArrayAndCopy(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    
    return Arrays.copyOf(arr, 2 * arr.length);
}
```

***Note**: However, sorting in this method may be skipped altogether as the data need to be re-sorted upon reading all the valid numbers.*

2. Size of the initial array should be doubled when the entire array is filled, so the condition should be corrected to `if (i == data.length)`
3. If not a number is encountered in the input data, the index of array should be decremented to skip invalid value.
4. As it is possible that the input data do not fill the entire array after several duplications of its size, it may be necessary to track actual count of numbers and sort the filled part of the array upon reading.

That being said, the code may be updated as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = new int[8];
    int numCount = 0;
    
    String input = "12 1 21 3 45 asv 56 7 32 44 reerg -23 55 0 32 12 thrt 34er "
                 + "23 tye 30 -18 234 40 332 91 32 84 22 102 -77 erg 33 -145";
    
    try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(input)) {
        for(int i = 0; myReader.hasNext(); i++) {
            
            if(i == data.length) {
                data = doubleArrayAndCopy(data);
                System.out.printf("%nDoubled: %s%n%n", Arrays.toString(data));
            }
            if(myReader.hasNextInt()) {
                data[i] = myReader.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("[%d]=%d  ", i, data[i]);
                numCount++; // counting valid numbers
            } else {
                myReader.next();
                i--; // skipping not-numbers
            }
        }
    }
    // sort only the valid numbers in the end
    Arrays.sort(data, 0, numCount);
    System.out.println("\nFinal: " + Arrays.toString(data));
}
```

Output:

```
[0]=12  [1]=1  [2]=21  [3]=3  [4]=45  [5]=56  [6]=7  [7]=32  
Doubled: [1, 3, 7, 12, 21, 32, 45, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[8]=44  [9]=-23  [10]=55  [11]=0  [12]=32  [13]=12  [14]=23  [15]=30  
Doubled: [-23, 0, 1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 21, 23, 30, 32, 32, 44, 45, 55, 56, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[16]=-18  [17]=234  [18]=40  [19]=332  [20]=91  [21]=32  [22]=84  [23]=22
[24]=102  [25]=-77  [26]=33  [27]=-145  
Final: [-145, -77, -23, -18, 0, 1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 21, 22, 23, 30, 32, 32, 32, 33,
40, 44, 45, 55, 56, 84, 91, 102, 234, 332, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

**Update**
An example of applying Stream API using Java 9 method [`Scanner::findAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll(java.lang.String)) without creating extra arrays:

```java
public static int[] getSortedIntInput(Scanner reader) {
    return reader
                .findAll("[-+]?\\d+") // Stream<MatchResult>
                .mapToInt(mr -> Integer.parseInt(mr.group(0))) // IntStream
                .sorted()
                .toArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "12 1 21 3 45 asv 56 7 32 44 reerg -23 55 0 32 12 thrt 34er "
                 + "23 tye 30 -18 234 40 332 91 32 84 22 102 -77 erg 33 -145";
    try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(input)) {
        int[] data = getSortedIntInput(myReader);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[-145, -77, -23, -18, 0, 1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 21, 22, 23, 30, 32, 32, 32, 33, 34, 40,
44, 45, 55, 56, 84, 91, 102, 234, 332]
```